# Rocket.rs: Optional PathBuf has no matching routes

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I'm creating a portfolio website and some projects have static HTML demos which I'd like to serve according to the ID in the URL. The route looks like this:

```rust
#[get("/demo/<id>/<pathbuf..>")]
fn site_demo(id: usize, pathbuf: Option<PathBuf>) -> Option<NamedFile> {
    // set path according to id
    let demo = format!{"static/projects/{:03}/demo/", id};
    // if `pathbuf` is not provided, set file to `index.html`
    let pathbuf = pathbuf.unwrap_or(PathBuf::from("index.html"));

    let path = Path::new(&demo).join(pathbuf);
    NamedFile::open(path).ok()
}
```

When I type `localhost:5050/demo/003/index.html` in my browser, the demo (and everything else in the demo folder) gets loaded. However, once I type just `localhost:5050/demo/003/` I get this error (same result without `/` at the end):

```
GET /demo/003/ text/html:
    => Error: No matching routes for GET /demo/003/ text/html.
    => Warning: Responding with 404 Not Found catcher.
    => Response succeeded.
```

I'd expect the route to match, because the `PathBuf` is optional and gets set to `index.html`. Would make sense to me...

Did I go wrong somewhere or should I open an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multiple segments path cannot be empty.

A different approach is to use 2 routes :

- one for the multiple segment `/demo/<id>/<pathbuf..>`
- one for the empty segment `/demo/<id>` that redirect to `/demo/<id>/index.html`

A sample using rust **nightly** and rocket **0.4** :

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]  
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

use std::path::{Path,PathBuf};
use rocket::response::{Redirect,NamedFile};

#[get("/demo/<id>/<pathbuf..>")]
fn site_demo(id: usize, pathbuf: PathBuf) -> Option<NamedFile> {
    let demo = format!{"static/projects/{:03}/demo/", id};
    NamedFile::open(Path::new(&demo).join(pathbuf)).ok()
}

#[get("/demo/<pathbuf..>", rank=2)]
fn redirect(pathbuf: PathBuf) -> Redirect {
    Redirect::to(format!{"/demo/{}/index.html", pathbuf.display()})
}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![site_demo,redirect]).launch();
}
```

A sample using rust **stable** and rocket **0.5** :

```
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

use std::path::{Path,PathBuf};
use rocket::response::{Redirect,NamedFile};

#[get("/demo/<id>/<pathbuf..>")]
async fn site_demo(id: usize, pathbuf: PathBuf) -> Option<NamedFile> {
    let demo = format!{"static/projects/{:03}/demo/", id};
    NamedFile::open(Path::new(&demo).join(pathbuf)).await.ok()
}

#[get("/demo/<pathbuf..>", rank=2)]
fn redirect(pathbuf: PathBuf) -> Redirect {
    Redirect::to(format!{"/demo/{}/index.html", pathbuf.display()})
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> rocket::Rocket {
    rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![site_demo,redirect])
}
```

Like this `localhost:5050/demo/003/` will be redirect to `localhost:5050/demo/003/index.html` and then `localhost:5050/demo/003/index.html` will load `static/projects/003/demo/index.html`

Comment: When I tried this, I got `conflicting implementation for "rocket::StaticRouteInfo"` errors.

Comment: @JonathanMayer: I just try with `rustc 1.51.0-nightly` and `rocket v0.4.6` and the proposed answer still work. Which version are you using ?

Comment: I'll try again this evening.  Possibly, the difference in my environment is that my paths are:

"/foo/<path..>"
vs
"/foo/<path..>?bar=<bar>"

Will retest tonight with nightly and report back.

Comment: This answer propose a solution to add index.html to a path if not specified, your case may be different